# Building Mobile Apps out of HTML5, with motion tracking?

Tags: android, html, web-applications, mobile-application

This is an open question and I was really hoping for advice...

I am planning on creating a mobile app which will track your steps and distance (based on GPS), while sitting in your pocket.

I was planning to make the app out of html5 as I know you can calcualte the motion of the device using this

So, I am really asking if people think this is possible on HTML5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know JavaScript, you should be able to accomplish this with PhoneGap's [Geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) object.

Appcelerator has [Titanium.Geolocation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to do it with HTML5 and PhoneGap is probably your best option. But you'll still need to program a `background service`* in order to handle tracking the location while the app isn't actively in use.

It sounds like the real work will need to be done in Java either way so I think you should just make a regular Android application. But as I said PhoneGap is still an option for the interface if that's what you really want.

* The background service will still need to be done with Android API's. Which would then need to be hooked into PhoneGap. It might just be simpler to make a native app.